# Postgres - How to restore a .sql file onto an existing database

Tags: postgresql

I need to restore a .sql Postgres backup into an existing database on a daily basis.

What I am currenty doing is this:

```
#Drop
psql -h databaseHost -p 5432 -U databaseUser -d postgres -c "DROP DATABASE myDatabase"

#Create a fresh DB
psql -h databaseHost -p 5432 -U databaseUser -d postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE myDatabase owner databaseOwner"

#Restore
psql -h databaseHost -p 5432 -U $databaseUser myDatabase < myDatabase.sql
```

What I am looking for is to be able to restore the .sql file on the existing database. I feel dropping and creating it afresh is something I can avoid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes you can avoid it, but it means reading the docs [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html).  Read sections `-c` and `-C`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the -f option:

```
psql -h databaseHost -p 5432 -U $databaseUser -d myDatabase -f myDatabase.sql
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).